# Get all controls inside AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabpanel

I am trying to iterate through all controls inside my page, which contains an ajaxtoolkit:tabcontainer with several ajaxtoolkit:tabpanel s. I am trying to do this recursively, like this:

```
protected override void AddedControl(Control control, int index)
{
   base.AddedControl(control, index);
   ParseControls(control);
}

public void ParseControls(Control control)
{
        foreach (Control myControl in control.Controls)
        {
            ParseControls(myControl);

            if(myControl.GetType().ToString().ToLower() == "AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel".ToLower())
            {
                AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tabPanel = (AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel)myControl;
                Response.Write("tabpanel id is:" + tabPanel.ID + " |tab panel no of controls:" + tabPanel.Controls.Count.ToString() + "<br />");
            }

        }
}
```

My problem here is that whenever I find a TabPanel I cannot iterate through its control collection because TabPanel.Controls.Count always returns 0, although in the aspx page I added textboxes, labels and so on. I also tried looking after an item inside the TabPanel with the FindControl method, but it didn't help me.

```
      HtmlTable tbl = (HtmlTable)tabPanel.FindControl("tblContent");
```

Can someone point me out what I'm missing? Thank you!

Comment: If you just access your `TabContainer` directly in code can you iterate over its Panels?

Comment: Same problem, I tried it also this way. It sees the TabPanels, but no controls inside them.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem. Here was my solution.

Briefly what it does. This will loop through all controls on your page. You can just pass in any type of control. Page or just the tabcontainer to the function. Then Check if the control is a TabPanel.If it is . Parse it to a TabPanel first and then Access the controls. 
Hope this helps

```
       private void IterateControls(Control ctrl)
    {
        foreach (Control item in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (item is AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel)
            {
                TabPanel tp = item as TabPanel;
                foreach (Control tpControls in tp.Controls)
                {
                    IterateControls(tpControls);
                }
            }
            else
                if (item.Controls.Count > 1)
                {

                    IterateControls(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
                    {
                        DropDownList dl = item as DropDownList;
                       //do something  

                    }
                    else if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                    {

                        TextBox txt = item as TextBox;
                        if (txt.ID == "testControlID")
                        {
                            //IT WORKS!! 
                        }
                        //do something  
                    }
                }
        }

    }
```

You can then just call the function like this

```
    IterateControls(Page);
```